# Same rank for two records in dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a trouble assigning the same rank to record nodes. Without `node [shape=record]` the graph works. Uncommenting that line and there's `lost B C edge` error.

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR
// uncommenting the following line gives "lost B C edge" error
//    node [shape=record]
    A--B
    A--C
    B--C
    {
        rank=same
        B
        C
    }
}
```

I do need record shape in my actual graph. I'm not just using it to get rectangular shape for nodes.

Answer (score 1):

When I un-comment the line (in http://www.webgraphviz.com/) I get:

[image]

Does the following give the result you want:

```
graph  {
    //rankdir=LR

    node [shape=record]
    A -- B
    A -- C
    B -- C
    {rank=same;B;C;}

}
```

i.e.

[image]

Otherwise
- please make a sketch of what you want.
- which version of graphviz are you using?

Comment: thank you! I was using a different site to render my graph, you can see the error here: [Here's the site with code displaying error,](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#graph%20{%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir=LR%0A%20%20%20%20node%20[shape=record]%0A%20%20%20%20A--B%0A%20%20%20%20A--C%0A%20%20%20%20B--C%0A%20%20%20%20{%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank=same%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%0A%20%20%20%20}%0A})

However, I'm not bound to it and from now on I'll use http://www.webgraphviz.com/